# How do I get the number of days in the previous month?

Tags: templating, datetime, calendar

I am working on a calendar, and so far I know how to get the number of days in the current month.
`{% set daysInMonth = time|date('t') %}`

But how can I get the number of days in the previous month?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe: `{{ now | date_modify('-1 month') | date('t') }}`